# GLMNET output produces flat MAE

Tags: r, recipe, tidymodels

I am wondering what I am doing incorrectly in my `recipe` of the below `reprex`. It seems to be producing a flat MAE across all hyperparameters. I am still learning how to use `tidymodels`, so perhaps I am missing a learning trick here, but reaching out to see if someone seasoned can help guide me here. Thanks!

```r
library(tidymodels)
#> ── Attaching packages ──────────────────────────── tidymodels 0.1.1 ──
#> ✓ broom     0.7.0      ✓ recipes   0.1.13
#> ✓ dials     0.0.8      ✓ rsample   0.0.7 
#> ✓ dplyr     1.0.2      ✓ tibble    3.0.3 
#> ✓ ggplot2   3.3.2      ✓ tidyr     1.1.2 
#> ✓ infer     0.5.3      ✓ tune      0.1.1 
#> ✓ modeldata 0.0.2      ✓ workflows 0.1.3 
#> ✓ parsnip   0.1.3      ✓ yardstick 0.0.7 
#> ✓ purrr     0.3.4
#> ── Conflicts ─────────────────────────────── tidymodels_conflicts() ──
#> x purrr::discard() masks scales::discard()
#> x dplyr::filter()  masks stats::filter()
#> x dplyr::lag()     masks stats::lag()
#> x recipes::step()  masks stats::step()

data(mtcars)

set.seed(101)
clean_split <- initial_split(mtcars, prop = 0.8)

train <- training(clean_split)
test <- testing(clean_split)


recipe <- recipe(mpg ~ ., data = train) %>%
       step_log(all_outcomes(), base = 10, skip = TRUE) %>%
       step_center(all_predictors(), -all_nominal()) %>%
       step_scale(all_predictors(), -all_nominal()) %>%
       step_other(all_nominal(), threshold = 0.01) %>%
       step_dummy(all_nominal()) %>% 
       step_zv(all_predictors(), -all_outcomes())

### Creating models
#### GLMNET
glmnet_model <- linear_reg(mode = "regression",
                           penalty = tune(),
                           mixture = tune()) %>%
       set_engine("glmnet")

glmnet_model
#> Linear Regression Model Specification (regression)
#> 
#> Main Arguments:
#>   penalty = tune()
#>   mixture = tune()
#> 
#> Computational engine: glmnet

glmnet_params <- parameters(penalty(), mixture())
glmnet_params
#> Collection of 2 parameters for tuning
#> 
#>       id parameter type object class
#>  penalty        penalty    nparam[+]
#>  mixture        mixture    nparam[+]

set.seed(123)
glmnet_grid <- grid_max_entropy(glmnet_params, size = 20)
glmnet_grid
#> # A tibble: 20 x 2
#>     penalty mixture
#>       <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 2.94e- 1  0.702 
#>  2 1.48e- 4  0.996 
#>  3 1.60e- 1  0.444 
#>  4 5.86e- 1  0.975 
#>  5 1.69e- 9  0.0491
#>  6 1.10e- 5  0.699 
#>  7 2.76e- 2  0.988 
#>  8 4.95e- 8  0.753 
#>  9 1.07e- 5  0.382 
#> 10 7.87e- 8  0.331 
#> 11 4.07e- 1  0.180 
#> 12 1.70e- 3  0.590 
#> 13 2.52e-10  0.382 
#> 14 2.47e-10  0.666 
#> 15 2.31e- 9  0.921 
#> 16 1.31e- 7  0.546 
#> 17 1.49e- 6  0.973 
#> 18 1.28e- 3  0.0224
#> 19 7.49e- 7  0.0747
#> 20 2.37e- 3  0.351


### Creating a workflow for each model
glmnet_wfl <- workflow() %>%
       add_recipe(recipe) %>%
       add_model(glmnet_model)

### Creating cross-validation splits
cv_splits <- vfold_cv(train, v = 5)
cv_splits
#> #  5-fold cross-validation 
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   splits         id   
#>   <list>         <chr>
#> 1 <split [20/6]> Fold1
#> 2 <split [21/5]> Fold2
#> 3 <split [21/5]> Fold3
#> 4 <split [21/5]> Fold4
#> 5 <split [21/5]> Fold5


### Training and tuning models
#### GLMNET
glmnet_stage_1_cv_results_tbl <- tune_grid(
       glmnet_wfl,
       resamples = cv_splits,
       grid = glmnet_grid,
       metrics = metric_set(mae, mape, rmse, rsq),
       control = control_grid(verbose = TRUE)
)
#> i Fold1: recipe
#> ✓ Fold1: recipe
#> i Fold1: model  1/20
#> ✓ Fold1: model  1/20
#> i Fold1: model  1/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: model  2/20
#> ✓ Fold1: model  2/20
#> i Fold1: model  2/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: model  3/20
#> ✓ Fold1: model  3/20
#> i Fold1: model  3/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: model  4/20
#> ✓ Fold1: model  4/20
#> i Fold1: model  4/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: model  5/20
#> ✓ Fold1: model  5/20
#> i Fold1: model  5/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: model  6/20
#> ✓ Fold1: model  6/20
#> i Fold1: model  6/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: model  7/20
#> ✓ Fold1: model  7/20
#> i Fold1: model  7/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: model  8/20
#> ✓ Fold1: model  8/20
#> i Fold1: model  8/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: model  9/20
#> ✓ Fold1: model  9/20
#> i Fold1: model  9/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: model 10/20
#> ✓ Fold1: model 10/20
#> i Fold1: model 10/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: model 11/20
#> ✓ Fold1: model 11/20
#> i Fold1: model 11/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: model 12/20
#> ✓ Fold1: model 12/20
#> i Fold1: model 12/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: model 13/20
#> ✓ Fold1: model 13/20
#> i Fold1: model 13/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: model 14/20
#> ✓ Fold1: model 14/20
#> i Fold1: model 14/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: model 15/20
#> ✓ Fold1: model 15/20
#> i Fold1: model 15/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: model 16/20
#> ✓ Fold1: model 16/20
#> i Fold1: model 16/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: model 17/20
#> ✓ Fold1: model 17/20
#> i Fold1: model 17/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: model 18/20
#> ✓ Fold1: model 18/20
#> i Fold1: model 18/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: model 19/20
#> ✓ Fold1: model 19/20
#> i Fold1: model 19/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold1: model 20/20
#> ✓ Fold1: model 20/20
#> i Fold1: model 20/20 (predictions)
#> ! Fold1: internal: A correlation computation is required, but `estimate` is const...
#> ✓ Fold1: internal
#> i Fold2: recipe
#> ✓ Fold2: recipe
#> i Fold2: model  1/20
#> ✓ Fold2: model  1/20
#> i Fold2: model  1/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: model  2/20
#> ✓ Fold2: model  2/20
#> i Fold2: model  2/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: model  3/20
#> ✓ Fold2: model  3/20
#> i Fold2: model  3/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: model  4/20
#> ✓ Fold2: model  4/20
#> i Fold2: model  4/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: model  5/20
#> ✓ Fold2: model  5/20
#> i Fold2: model  5/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: model  6/20
#> ✓ Fold2: model  6/20
#> i Fold2: model  6/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: model  7/20
#> ✓ Fold2: model  7/20
#> i Fold2: model  7/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: model  8/20
#> ✓ Fold2: model  8/20
#> i Fold2: model  8/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: model  9/20
#> ✓ Fold2: model  9/20
#> i Fold2: model  9/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: model 10/20
#> ✓ Fold2: model 10/20
#> i Fold2: model 10/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: model 11/20
#> ✓ Fold2: model 11/20
#> i Fold2: model 11/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: model 12/20
#> ✓ Fold2: model 12/20
#> i Fold2: model 12/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: model 13/20
#> ✓ Fold2: model 13/20
#> i Fold2: model 13/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: model 14/20
#> ✓ Fold2: model 14/20
#> i Fold2: model 14/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: model 15/20
#> ✓ Fold2: model 15/20
#> i Fold2: model 15/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: model 16/20
#> ✓ Fold2: model 16/20
#> i Fold2: model 16/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: model 17/20
#> ✓ Fold2: model 17/20
#> i Fold2: model 17/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: model 18/20
#> ✓ Fold2: model 18/20
#> i Fold2: model 18/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: model 19/20
#> ✓ Fold2: model 19/20
#> i Fold2: model 19/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold2: model 20/20
#> ✓ Fold2: model 20/20
#> i Fold2: model 20/20 (predictions)
#> ! Fold2: internal: A correlation computation is required, but `estimate` is const...
#> ✓ Fold2: internal
#> i Fold3: recipe
#> ✓ Fold3: recipe
#> i Fold3: model  1/20
#> ✓ Fold3: model  1/20
#> i Fold3: model  1/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: model  2/20
#> ✓ Fold3: model  2/20
#> i Fold3: model  2/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: model  3/20
#> ✓ Fold3: model  3/20
#> i Fold3: model  3/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: model  4/20
#> ✓ Fold3: model  4/20
#> i Fold3: model  4/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: model  5/20
#> ✓ Fold3: model  5/20
#> i Fold3: model  5/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: model  6/20
#> ✓ Fold3: model  6/20
#> i Fold3: model  6/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: model  7/20
#> ✓ Fold3: model  7/20
#> i Fold3: model  7/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: model  8/20
#> ✓ Fold3: model  8/20
#> i Fold3: model  8/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: model  9/20
#> ✓ Fold3: model  9/20
#> i Fold3: model  9/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: model 10/20
#> ✓ Fold3: model 10/20
#> i Fold3: model 10/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: model 11/20
#> ✓ Fold3: model 11/20
#> i Fold3: model 11/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: model 12/20
#> ✓ Fold3: model 12/20
#> i Fold3: model 12/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: model 13/20
#> ✓ Fold3: model 13/20
#> i Fold3: model 13/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: model 14/20
#> ✓ Fold3: model 14/20
#> i Fold3: model 14/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: model 15/20
#> ✓ Fold3: model 15/20
#> i Fold3: model 15/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: model 16/20
#> ✓ Fold3: model 16/20
#> i Fold3: model 16/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: model 17/20
#> ✓ Fold3: model 17/20
#> i Fold3: model 17/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: model 18/20
#> ✓ Fold3: model 18/20
#> i Fold3: model 18/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: model 19/20
#> ✓ Fold3: model 19/20
#> i Fold3: model 19/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold3: model 20/20
#> ✓ Fold3: model 20/20
#> i Fold3: model 20/20 (predictions)
#> ! Fold3: internal: A correlation computation is required, but `estimate` is const...
#> ✓ Fold3: internal
#> i Fold4: recipe
#> ✓ Fold4: recipe
#> i Fold4: model  1/20
#> ✓ Fold4: model  1/20
#> i Fold4: model  1/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: model  2/20
#> ✓ Fold4: model  2/20
#> i Fold4: model  2/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: model  3/20
#> ✓ Fold4: model  3/20
#> i Fold4: model  3/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: model  4/20
#> ✓ Fold4: model  4/20
#> i Fold4: model  4/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: model  5/20
#> ✓ Fold4: model  5/20
#> i Fold4: model  5/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: model  6/20
#> ✓ Fold4: model  6/20
#> i Fold4: model  6/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: model  7/20
#> ✓ Fold4: model  7/20
#> i Fold4: model  7/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: model  8/20
#> ✓ Fold4: model  8/20
#> i Fold4: model  8/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: model  9/20
#> ✓ Fold4: model  9/20
#> i Fold4: model  9/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: model 10/20
#> ✓ Fold4: model 10/20
#> i Fold4: model 10/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: model 11/20
#> ✓ Fold4: model 11/20
#> i Fold4: model 11/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: model 12/20
#> ✓ Fold4: model 12/20
#> i Fold4: model 12/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: model 13/20
#> ✓ Fold4: model 13/20
#> i Fold4: model 13/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: model 14/20
#> ✓ Fold4: model 14/20
#> i Fold4: model 14/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: model 15/20
#> ✓ Fold4: model 15/20
#> i Fold4: model 15/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: model 16/20
#> ✓ Fold4: model 16/20
#> i Fold4: model 16/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: model 17/20
#> ✓ Fold4: model 17/20
#> i Fold4: model 17/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: model 18/20
#> ✓ Fold4: model 18/20
#> i Fold4: model 18/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: model 19/20
#> ✓ Fold4: model 19/20
#> i Fold4: model 19/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold4: model 20/20
#> ✓ Fold4: model 20/20
#> i Fold4: model 20/20 (predictions)
#> ! Fold4: internal: A correlation computation is required, but `estimate` is const...
#> ✓ Fold4: internal
#> i Fold5: recipe
#> ✓ Fold5: recipe
#> i Fold5: model  1/20
#> ✓ Fold5: model  1/20
#> i Fold5: model  1/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: model  2/20
#> ✓ Fold5: model  2/20
#> i Fold5: model  2/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: model  3/20
#> ✓ Fold5: model  3/20
#> i Fold5: model  3/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: model  4/20
#> ✓ Fold5: model  4/20
#> i Fold5: model  4/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: model  5/20
#> ✓ Fold5: model  5/20
#> i Fold5: model  5/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: model  6/20
#> ✓ Fold5: model  6/20
#> i Fold5: model  6/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: model  7/20
#> ✓ Fold5: model  7/20
#> i Fold5: model  7/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: model  8/20
#> ✓ Fold5: model  8/20
#> i Fold5: model  8/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: model  9/20
#> ✓ Fold5: model  9/20
#> i Fold5: model  9/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: model 10/20
#> ✓ Fold5: model 10/20
#> i Fold5: model 10/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: model 11/20
#> ✓ Fold5: model 11/20
#> i Fold5: model 11/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: model 12/20
#> ✓ Fold5: model 12/20
#> i Fold5: model 12/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: model 13/20
#> ✓ Fold5: model 13/20
#> i Fold5: model 13/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: model 14/20
#> ✓ Fold5: model 14/20
#> i Fold5: model 14/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: model 15/20
#> ✓ Fold5: model 15/20
#> i Fold5: model 15/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: model 16/20
#> ✓ Fold5: model 16/20
#> i Fold5: model 16/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: model 17/20
#> ✓ Fold5: model 17/20
#> i Fold5: model 17/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: model 18/20
#> ✓ Fold5: model 18/20
#> i Fold5: model 18/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: model 19/20
#> ✓ Fold5: model 19/20
#> i Fold5: model 19/20 (predictions)
#> i Fold5: model 20/20
#> ✓ Fold5: model 20/20
#> i Fold5: model 20/20 (predictions)
#> ! Fold5: internal: A correlation computation is required, but `estimate` is const...
#> ✓ Fold5: internal
glmnet_stage_1_cv_results_tbl %>% show_best("mae", n = 10)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 8
#>     penalty mixture .metric .estimator  mean     n std_err .config
#>       <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>      <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>  
#>  1 4.95e- 8  0.753  mae     standard    19.1     5    1.56 Model15
#>  2 1.49e- 6  0.973  mae     standard    19.1     5    1.56 Model17
#>  3 2.31e- 9  0.921  mae     standard    19.1     5    1.56 Model16
#>  4 1.10e- 5  0.699  mae     standard    19.1     5    1.56 Model13
#>  5 1.31e- 7  0.546  mae     standard    19.1     5    1.56 Model10
#>  6 2.47e-10  0.666  mae     standard    19.1     5    1.56 Model12
#>  7 7.87e- 8  0.331  mae     standard    19.1     5    1.56 Model05
#>  8 1.07e- 5  0.382  mae     standard    19.1     5    1.56 Model08
#>  9 2.52e-10  0.382  mae     standard    19.1     5    1.56 Model07
#> 10 7.49e- 7  0.0747 mae     standard    19.1     5    1.56 Model03
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It would seem that if I remove the ```skip = TRUE```from the ```step_log```, the MAEs produced are as expected. So, I am curious if this option is only used is explicitly using ```prep```and ```bake``` on recipes, rather than automating it with ```workflow```? [Reference](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/reference/step_log.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transforming the outcome within a recipe can be very tricky. Say you do indeed need to do something like:

```r
step_log(mpg, base = 10)
```

This will cause a failure when the recipe is applied to new data when the outcome is not known. Since fuel efficiency is what we are trying to predict, there probably won't be a column in the data for this variable. In fact, to avoid *information leakage*, during tuning with `tune_grid()` the data being used to train each model is isolated from that being used to assess each model. This means that the training set and any outcome columns are not available for use at prediction time.

#### For simple transformations of the **outcome** column(s), we strongly suggest that those operations be *conducted outside of the recipe*.

```r
library(tidymodels)

log_car <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(mpg = log10(mpg))

set.seed(101)
clean_split <- initial_split(log_car, prop = 0.8)

train <- training(clean_split)
test <- testing(clean_split)


recipe <- recipe(mpg ~ ., data = train) %>%
  step_other(all_nominal(), threshold = 0.01) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal()) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_predictors(), -all_nominal()) %>%
  step_zv(all_predictors(), -all_outcomes())

glmnet_model <- linear_reg(mode = "regression",
                           penalty = tune(),
                           mixture = tune()) %>%
  set_engine("glmnet")

glmnet_model
#> Linear Regression Model Specification (regression)
#> 
#> Main Arguments:
#>   penalty = tune()
#>   mixture = tune()
#> 
#> Computational engine: glmnet

set.seed(123)
glmnet_grid <- grid_max_entropy(penalty(), mixture(), size = 20)
glmnet_grid
#> # A tibble: 20 x 2
#>     penalty mixture
#>       <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1 2.94e- 1  0.702 
#>  2 1.48e- 4  0.996 
#>  3 1.60e- 1  0.444 
#>  4 5.86e- 1  0.975 
#>  5 1.69e- 9  0.0491
#>  6 1.10e- 5  0.699 
#>  7 2.76e- 2  0.988 
#>  8 4.95e- 8  0.753 
#>  9 1.07e- 5  0.382 
#> 10 7.87e- 8  0.331 
#> 11 4.07e- 1  0.180 
#> 12 1.70e- 3  0.590 
#> 13 2.52e-10  0.382 
#> 14 2.47e-10  0.666 
#> 15 2.31e- 9  0.921 
#> 16 1.31e- 7  0.546 
#> 17 1.49e- 6  0.973 
#> 18 1.28e- 3  0.0224
#> 19 7.49e- 7  0.0747
#> 20 2.37e- 3  0.351

glmnet_wfl <- workflow() %>%
  add_recipe(recipe) %>%
  add_model(glmnet_model)


cv_splits <- vfold_cv(train, v = 5)
cv_splits
#> #  5-fold cross-validation 
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   splits         id   
#>   <list>         <chr>
#> 1 <split [20/6]> Fold1
#> 2 <split [21/5]> Fold2
#> 3 <split [21/5]> Fold3
#> 4 <split [21/5]> Fold4
#> 5 <split [21/5]> Fold5

glmnet_stage_1_cv_results_tbl <- tune_grid(
  glmnet_wfl,
  resamples = cv_splits,
  grid = glmnet_grid,
  metrics = metric_set(mae)
)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'Matrix'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     expand, pack, unpack
#> Loaded glmnet 4.0-2

glmnet_stage_1_cv_results_tbl %>% 
  show_best("mae", n = 10)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 8
#>     penalty mixture .metric .estimator   mean     n std_err .config
#>       <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>       <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>  
#>  1 1.70e- 3  0.590  mae     standard   0.0396     5 0.00583 Model11
#>  2 2.37e- 3  0.351  mae     standard   0.0400     5 0.00597 Model06
#>  3 1.28e- 3  0.0224 mae     standard   0.0433     5 0.00592 Model01
#>  4 1.48e- 4  0.996  mae     standard   0.0462     5 0.00538 Model20
#>  5 2.76e- 2  0.988  mae     standard   0.0465     5 0.00699 Model19
#>  6 1.69e- 9  0.0491 mae     standard   0.0470     5 0.00536 Model02
#>  7 7.49e- 7  0.0747 mae     standard   0.0474     5 0.00539 Model03
#>  8 2.47e-10  0.666  mae     standard   0.0476     5 0.00545 Model12
#>  9 1.10e- 5  0.699  mae     standard   0.0476     5 0.00546 Model13
#> 10 2.31e- 9  0.921  mae     standard   0.0476     5 0.00547 Model16
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>

Comment: This makes sense now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Quick question: what would be the best way to `predict` on new data and then adjust for the log transformation, using `tidymodels`?

Comment: The predictions will be on the scale of the logged outcome this way, just like if you did something like `lm(log(mpg) ~ ., data = mtcars)`, so you would need to adjust in the same way with either approach.